# Second degree differential equation into two first degree equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do i transform this:

$\frac{(d^2\theta)}{(dt^2)}(t) = -\frac{g}{L}sin(\theta(t))$

Where g and L are constants

to these two first order differential equations:

1) $\frac{dv}{dt} = -gsin(\theta)$
2) $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{L}v$

knowing that:

$v(t) = L\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t)$

Comment: Those are not linear equations

Comment: The result you are asking about immediately follows from the definition of $v$

Comment: Yes i see how i can find out the second one, but not the first one

Comment: How is the second derivative of a function related to the first derivative?

Comment: haha just got it, thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know that $$ v(t)=L\frac {d\theta}{dt}$$
Your second equation is found by solving the above equation for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$

The first equation is then found by differentiating the given equation and substitutin for $ \frac {d^2\theta}{dt^2} $ from your original second order equation .